# enum.ValueOf requires fully qualified path?

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to use valueOf in Java to parse a String into an enum and it seems to be requiring a fully qualified path to the enum as the String which controverts examples on SO and other places. For example:

```
String sRange = "region";
order.range = ItemOrder.eRange.valueOf( sRange );
```

where ItemOrder.eRange is:

```
class ItemOrder {
    public enum eRange {
        area,
        zone,
        region
    }
}
```

gives the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum
>   constant ItemOrder.eRange.region"     at
>   java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, so I suspect it's somewhere in how you're diagnosing the issue. Please post a [mcve]. I'd also strongly advise you to start following Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is somewhat subtle: a quotation mark.

If you look closely at the error message, you will see that the String being supplied to valueOf is not `region`, but is `region"` with a trailing quotation mark. It looks like the quotation mark is part of the error message, but it is not, it is part of the value, and that is leading to the mismatch.